# Definite integral with Bessel-J function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I try to find an closed form answer the following integral,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\,x^{m}J_l(Qx)e^{-x^2},\quad m\in\mathbb{Z}, l\in\mathbb{Z},Q>0$$
where $J_l(Qx)$ is Bessel function of the first kind, but I am not sure that it exists. Can anybody help me?

Wolfram Mathematica says that the answer (with assumption $\mathrm{Re}\,(l+m)>-1$) is
$$2^{-l-1}Q^l\Gamma\left(\frac{m+l+1}{2}\right){}_1\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{m+l+1}{2},l+1,-\frac{Q^2}{4}\right),$$
where ${}_1\tilde{F}_1$ is regularized confluent hypergeometric function. However, I feel that due to $m,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ more simple answer can exist.

Comment: please define $J_l$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 I have edited the question

Comment: not sure if this relationship would help at all (found on another post here) $$e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}=\lim_{\nu\rightarrow\infty}\Gamma(\nu+1)\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt\nu x}\right)^\nu J_\nu\left(\sqrt{\nu} x\right),$$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 to be honest, I do not understand how it can help. You suggest to plug this representation of exp into the integral?

Comment: maybe yes ... and then orthogonality of Bessel junctions perhaps ...

Comment: It can be found in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik as formula number 6.631.1.